# Get auth parameters in Laravel login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want unique url for every user when he log in.

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('USERNAME', 'HomeController@index'); // <--- this part
Route::get('about', 'PagesController@about');
Route::get('contact', 'PagesController@contact');

Route::pattern('id', '[0-9]+');
Route::get('news/{id}', 'ArticlesController@show');
Route::get('video/{id}', 'VideoController@show');
Route::get('photo/{id}', 'PhotoController@show');

Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);


if (Request::is('admin/*'))
{
    require __DIR__.'/admin_routes.php';
}
```

**AuthControler.php**

```
protected $redirectTo = 'USERNAME'; // <--- this part

/**
 * Create a new authentication controller instance.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard  $auth
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar  $registrar
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Guard $auth, Registrar $registrar)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
    $this->registrar = $registrar;

    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
}
```

I want when user log in to have url like **www.somesite.com/USERNAME**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('about', 'PagesController@about');
Route::get('contact', 'PagesController@contact');

Route::pattern('id', '[0-9]+');
Route::get('news/{id}', 'ArticlesController@show');
Route::get('video/{id}', 'VideoController@show');
Route::get('photo/{id}', 'PhotoController@show');

Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);

Route::get('{username}', 'HomeController@index'); // <--- this part


if (Request::is('admin/*'))
{
    require __DIR__.'/admin_routes.php';
}
```

You want that if there are no matched routes use the HomeController@index. With this code you can do that. However this isn't the best option in my opinion. What if a person has a username 'about'. Then he is redirected to the about page. I suggest doing something like this:

```
Route::get('users/{username}', 'HomeController@user');
```

In you're homecontroller you can do this:

```
public function user($username)
{
    //$username contains the username
    //or something Auth::user()->username gives you the username
}
```

Comment: OK, one part of problem solved, but how to get username value. {username} dont give back value.

Comment: Updated the answer. Is this what you're looking for? Else can you a little bit more specific?